# More efficient way to get UTC offset of a named timezone (e.g. -21600 for US/Central)

Tags: php, datetime, timezone, timezone-offset

Is there a more efficient way to convert timezone strings like `US/Central` to `-21600` than the following? Perhaps one that doesn't require loading both DateTimes and comparing?

```
echo getUtcOffset('America/Chicago');  // returns -21600
echo getUtcOffset('America/New_York'); // returns -18000
echo getUtcOffset('Indian/Mauritius'); // returns 14400
echo getUtcOffset('Europe/London');    // returns 0
function getUtcOffset($tz) {
    $utc_dtz = new DateTimeZone('UTC');
    $remote_dtz = new DateTimeZone($tz);
    $utc_dt = new DateTime("now", $utc_dtz);
    $remote_dt = new DateTime("now", $remote_dtz);
    $offset = $remote_dtz->getOffset($remote_dt) - $utc_dtz->getOffset($utc_dt);
    return $offset;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be as simple as this:

> [`DateTime::getOffset`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.getoffset.php)
>
> Returns the timezone offset.
>
> Returns the timezone offset in seconds from UTC on success or FALSE on
>   failure.

```
function getUtcOffset1($tz) {
    $datetime = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone($tz));
    return $datetime->getOffset();
}
echo getUtcOffset1('America/Chicago');  // returns -21600
echo getUtcOffset1('America/New_York'); // returns -18000
echo getUtcOffset1('Indian/Mauritius'); // returns 14400
```